# The parameters for knitting a parent document containing child documents that have loaded external scripts

Tags: r, parameters, r-markdown, knitr

there are two script(test1.R & test2.R)

[test1.R]

```
# ---- attribution ----
input_params <- 
  list(headline = "性",
       attribution = "sex")


# ---- testA ----

data <- tribble(  # 例示用にてきとうにgeneration列を追加
  ~sex, ~generation, ~high, ~n,
  "男性", 10, "high", 38,
  "男性", 10, "low", 148,
  "女性", 10, "high", 10,
  "女性", 20, "low", 33) # 実際には年代の集計等も行っている

dat <- 
  data |>
  group_by(!!sym(input_params$attribution)) |>   
  # summarize(hoge) |>  # 実際コード推定
  pivot_wider( names_from =  input_params$attribution, 
               values_from = "n") |>
  print()
```

[test2.R]

```
# ---- attribution ----
input_params <- 
  list(headline = "年代",
       attribution = "generation")


# ---- testA ----

data <- tribble(  # 例示用にてきとうにgeneration列を追加
  ~sex, ~generation, ~high, ~n,
  "男性", 10, "high", 38,
  "男性", 10, "low", 148,
  "女性", 10, "high", 10,
  "女性", 20, "low", 33) # 実際には年代の集計等も行っている

dat <- 
  data |>
  group_by(!!sym(input_params$attribution)) |>   
  # summarize(hoge) |>  # 実際コード推定
  pivot_wider( names_from =  input_params$attribution, 
               values_from = "n") |>
  print()
```

I load each of these two scripts into two separate Rmarkdown files.(child1.Rmd & child2.Rmd)

[child1.Rmd]

```
---
title: "child1"
output: html_document
---

``{r, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
``

``{r, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk('test1.R')
options(knitr.duplicate.label = "allow")
``

``{r, attribution, echo=FALSE}

``

# `r input_params$headline`別比較

``{r, testA, echo=FALSE}


``
```

[child2.Rmd]

```
---
title: "child2"
output: html_document
---

``{r, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
``

``{r, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk('test2.R')
options(knitr.duplicate.label = "allow")
``

``{r, attribution, echo=FALSE}

``

# `r input_params$headline`別比較

``{r, testA, echo=FALSE}


``
```

Finally, I knit these two child documents in the parent document(parent.Rmd).

[parent.Rmd]

```
---
title: "parent"
output: html_document
---

``{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
``


``{r, child=c("child1.Rmd","child2.Rmd")}

``
```

The result is that only the output for child1.Rmd is generated, and child2.Rmd does not produce any output.

I am looking to have child1.Rmd and child2.Rmd each reflect their respective attributions, resulting in the generation of two separate outputs.
However, only one output is being generated as shown in the image.[image]
How can I generate results for both documents?